# How to use notifyDataSetChanged() correctly to update my reyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to understand how to use notifyDataSetChanged() correctly in my MainActivity.
I want it to start right after the dialogfragment that gets the contact info from the user is closed.

I added it to end of storeDataInArrays() so that it updates the list whenever a new contact is added but currently it doesn't do anything.

I do not get any errors in logcat either so I do not know what I'm doing incorrectly.

This is the mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
//widgets
public ImageButton eAddContact;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

DatabaseHelper myDB;
ArrayList<String>Contact_id,Contact_Name,Contact_Number;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    eAddContact = findViewById(R.id.btnAddContact);
    eAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onClick:opening dialog");
            Dialog_AddContact dialog = new Dialog_AddContact();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Add Contact Dialog");
        }
    });
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"@#",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    Contact_id = new ArrayList<>();
    Contact_Name = new ArrayList<>();
    Contact_Number = new ArrayList<>();
    storeDataInArrays();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    customAdapter= new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,Contact_id,Contact_Name,Contact_Number);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    }
    void storeDataInArrays(){
        Cursor cursor = myDB.getEveryone();
        if(cursor.getCount()==0){
            //Add blank page
        }
        else{
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                Contact_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                Contact_Name.add(cursor.getString(1));
                Contact_Number.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }
        }
        customAdapter= new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,Contact_id,Contact_Name,Contact_Number);
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any and all help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `storeDataInArrays`, you do not need to create a `new CustomAdapter(...)`, just call `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Besides that, you might want to clean up your code and follow some standards for your code style. [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

or check out this article: [Android Coding Style and Guidelines](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-coding-style-and-guidelines/)

Comment: ah I see, just calling 'customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' works when I call the 'storeDataInArrays' function after initializing the adapter in the onCreate of the activity.
But the current issue of the recyclerview not refreshing when the contact is added still persists.
Also Thank you for the guide,will try to be careful about messy code from now on.

Comment: Are you updating the size inside your adapter when you override `getItemCount`?

Comment: apologies if I understood the question wrong, I currently have `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the else statement. In the same place it is in right now. 
I managed to solve my issue by calling the `storeDatainArrays()` method in the dialogfragment where I am recording the contact by using                 `((MainActivity)getActivity()).storeDataInArrays();` in the dialogfragment . Although I am not sure about how it affects performance, it does seem to work exactly the way I wanted.